# How to assert with NUNIT that a collection of dates is in ascending or descending order

Tags: selenium, sorting, nunit-3.0

I'm writing a couple of tests with Selenium to check if a list of dates on a webpage are sorted in descending or ascending order. The dates are formatted as follows: dd-mm-yyyy.

For other Alfanumeric items on this webpage I'm using the CollectionOrderedConstraint Is.Ordered Ascending and Descending from the NUNIT3 framework. For dates in the mentioned format this is not suitable.

Is there a way with NUNIT3 to accomplish this check?

If not how to accomplish this in another way with the use of C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do things like this I usually just scrape the page to get the list of `DateTime`, make a clone of the list, sort the cloned list, and then compare it to the original using `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()`. If the original list wasn't sorted correctly, the comparison will fail. An example...

```
[Test]
public void CompareDatesFail()
{
    // dates are NOT in order
    DateTime[] dates = { ParseDate("15-01-2020"), ParseDate("15-03-2020"), ParseDate("15-02-2020") };
    VerifyDatesAreSorted(dates);
}

[Test]
public void CompareDatesPass()
{
    // dates are in order
    DateTime[] dates = { ParseDate("15-01-2020"), ParseDate("15-02-2020"), ParseDate("15-03-2020") };
    VerifyDatesAreSorted(dates);
}
```

Since you will likely be doing a lot of string to `DateTime` parsing, I created a method that handles this in one place.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the DateTime for the provided dd-MM-yyyy formatted string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dateTimeString">The dd-MM-yyyy formatted string</param>
/// <returns>A DateTime instance</returns>
public DateTime ParseDate(string dateTimeString)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Since this verification will likely happen multiple times, wrap the code up in a method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Verifies that the provided array of DateTime instances are sorted
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dates">An array of DateTime instances</param>
public void VerifyDatesAreSorted(DateTime[] dates)
{
    DateTime[] sortedDates = (DateTime[])dates.Clone();
    Array.Sort(sortedDates);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(sortedDates, dates, "Verify dates are sorted");
}
```

Some references
[DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact)
[Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Seems  to me an elegant solution , I will try it out tomorrow and let you know if it is useful for me.